# Capture all $http premises with Angular

Tags: http, angularjs, callback

I would like to refresh the state of the user that is used in the navbar. but now I have to call `.all(function() { refresh() });` on all `$http.post` premises.

Could I capture all of them with a configuration for instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
app.config(function($httpProvider, $provide) {
  // This sucks but Angular is so compliated that we can't get the rootScope
  // in a simple way inside a factory for a configuration
  function getRootScope() {
    return angular.element('body').scope();
  }

  // Call refresh() after each HTTP destructive action
  $provide.factory('refreshAfterRequests', function($q) {
    return {
      'response': function(response) {
        // Every non-GET request can potentialy change the state of the user
        if (response.config.method !== 'GET') {
          getRootScope().refresh();
        }

        return response;
      }
    };
  });

  // The refresh is an interceptor on all HTTP requests made with Angular
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('refreshAfterRequests');
});
```

If someone have something better like how to get the scope from the inside the interceptor, I will gladly change this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can [intercept `$http` using request/response interceptors](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http).

But a better design might be to set a `$watch` in the `controller` for the navigation bar on a property the POST calls change (possibly on `$rootScope`, though it is not recommended).